# How to run Azure virtual machine from PowerShell script in C#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, .net-core, virtual-machine

I want to run my virtual machine from C# script, if i try to do this from PowerShell(5.1.18362.752 version) it works,
i put first command

`Import-AzureRmContext -Path "C:\Program Files(x86)\WindowsPowerShell\azureprofile.json"`

and then second command

`$PowerState = ((Get-AzureRmVM -Name Janusz -ResourceGroupName Inzynierska -Status).Statuses[1]).code
If ( $PowerState -contains "PowerState/running")
{
Write-Host "PowerState1: running"
}
ElseIf ( $PowerState -contains "PowerState/deallocated")
{
Start-AzureRmVM -Name Janusz -ResourceGroupName Inzynierska
$PowerState = ((Get-AzureRmVM -Name Janusz -ResourceGroupName Inzynierska -Status).Statuses[1]).code
}
Write-Host "PowerState2: $PowerState"`

but if i try to do this in C# .Net Core ,Visual Studio it's doesn't work

```
static void  Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {

                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Krute\Desktop\Inżynierka\PowerShellScriptRunning\FirstScript.txt");
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(text);

                IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke();
                while (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pierwsze Zapytanie");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                }
            }
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance1 = PowerShell.Create())
            {

                string text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Krute\Desktop\Inżynierka\PowerShellScriptRunning\SecondScript.txt");
                PowerShellInstance1.AddScript(text1);

                IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance1.BeginInvoke();

                while (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Drugie Zapytanie");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
            }
            Console.Read();
```

I check what is inside text and text1 and script is read correct.
Can somebody explain me what is wrong with my code or why it doesn't work? and what i can do to run this PowerShell script from C# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run PowerShell script from C# like this

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"D:\PSScripts\MyScript.ps1", true).Invoke();
```

Reference:

[Adding and invoking commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7#addscript)

Comment: When I changed the code to the one you recommended and changed the script extension from txt to ps1 then nothing changed, the machine still won't boot