# Run a batch file or a shell script in Azure Linux/Windows VM from Azure function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I understand, we can use Invoke Run command from azure function to execute a .bat/.sh script on remote VM. Is there a way to do the same over REST API, without writing any custom script/package?
Invoke Run command needs Powershell based Azure function. Is there any other way to do it, say from .NET core, Java or Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078981/16630138 - This may help (Writing the PS Script in C# Azure Function)

Answer (score 0):

> Run a batch file or a shell script in Azure Linux/Windows VM from Azure function

You can use C# for this and you use below code which works for me and I followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984003/calling-powershell-azure-module-and-creating-resource-group-from-c-sharp) of mine.

```cs
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    
    var ins = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
    ins.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
    
    using var ps = PowerShell.Create(ins);
    var results = ps.AddScript(@"
    
    az login
    
    az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name ""name of Vm"" -g ""name of resource group"" --scripts ""C:\test.ps1  rithwik bojja""     
    ").Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine(results);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Here I have used `AddScript` for call the commands. The script in VM takes two inputs(i have sent 1 has rithwik another input as bojja)
Script in VM:

```
param(
     [string]$a1,
     [string]$a2
  )
Write-Host Hello $a1 and  $a2
```

Comment: Where did you add this code. Looks like the namespaces will need .NET 8.0 and above. Azure function as of today supports .6.0 (LTS). I need this code to be executed from Azure function. Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: No i need .NET 6.0 for this.

Comment: Although I added this line
```<PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="6.0.1" />```

I get the following error
Error: Package System.Management.Automation 7.4.0-preview.3 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package System.Management.Automation 7.4.0-preview.3 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

Comment: PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.6" use this

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja. I was able to make progress. However, it now failed with a more concrete error
```
The term 'az' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```
Am I missing any package that need to be included?

Comment: Here's the code https://github.com/KrishnanSriram/fneusosexecutorwin

Comment: ```Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Scope CurrentUser –Force
Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser –Force
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

Import-Module 'Az'
Import-Module 'Az.Accounts'
Import-Module 'Az.RecoveryServices' ```inlude these before az login like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74012855/17623802)

Comment: I exactly did that, but now it complains Install-PackageProvider is not available
"2023-05-29T15:01:07Z   [Information]   The term 'Install-PackageProvider' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2023-05-29T15:01:07Z   [Information]   The 'new-object' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'."